# R- Split a dataframe based the numeric value of a column

Tags: r, split

Ok - it is straight forward enough to split a dataframe up by factor like so:

```
set.seed(10)

df <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:2]), 5)
)

split(df, df$g)
```

But I am struggling how to figure out how to split the data into a list by a numeric value - in this case x. I can imagine a solution with `ifelse()`  where you create another column in the data conditional upon where you want the data split (say 3). But I am wondering if there is a cleaner solution that behaves like `split` but use the value of a number. This works but it adds more code than I'd like

```
df$Group <- ifelse(df$x>3,"Group1","Group2")

split(df, df$Group)
```

So in the dataframe `df`, can it be split so that one element of the list is all values greater than 3 and the other element are all values less than or equal to 3?

Comment: have a look at `?cut`

Comment: `split(df, df$x > 3)` - just split on the logical outcome of checking if `x` is greater than 3.

Comment: What I need is something that returns a list of the two dataframes. I considered `cut` but I don't know if I can coerce it to output a list of dataframes.

Comment: @thelatemail - perfect and it should have been obvious. I combined `ifelse()` and  your solution to be able to label the groups. If you add yours as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @thelatemail add as answer? Boshek, you can add your own answer and accept.